# How can I assign a key frame to the bevel effect

Tags: animation, bevel

I want to make an animation with the bevel effect, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You only need to set the key frame from the Bevel field by hovering your mouse over it and hitting I.

You need to use the Bevel modifier and not use ctrl+B in Edit mode. You can find it the right side of your screen, on the Properties panel, if you click on Modifiers (the little wrench icon) the list of available modifiers will appear and you just need to click on Bevel to call the Bevel window, then you hover over the Width field and press I to generate a key frame.

Do that at the beginning of the animation, to set the starting point, then change the value on the Bevel Width field to what you want to have at the end of the animation, make sure you are at the end frame as well and hit I again while your mouse is hovering over the Bevel field.

Comment: I'm sorry I' new, what do you mean bevel field? I've just been using ctrl b in edit mode.

Comment: No worries, we all had to start at some point. On the right side of your screen, on the Properties panel, if you click on Modifiers (the little wrench icon) you will see the Bevel window, and you hover over the Width field and press I to generate a key frame. More on the Bevel modifier here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html?highlight=bevel

Comment: it looks like he has made a bevel in Edit mode and not with a Bevel modifier. If you don't want to use a modifier, you can change the positions of your edges in Edit mode and save them as keyframes, but you can't have zero bevel at keyframe 1 and create a bevel at keyframe 2